# Яндекс метрика везде

Tags: html, google-chrome, yandex-metrika-api

При загрузке любых сайтов, в исходном коде обнаружил одну и туже строку в блоке head.

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js"></script>
```

Иногда она же дублируется и после body страницы. На загружаемых страницах нету никаких метрик вообще.

И даже сейчас, используя Django, создавая чистые страницы, в выдаваемых страницах есть яндекс метрика.

И меня это настораживает. Пока что единственным местом где она стабильно не появляется, это в ручную написанный файл с обычной разметкой. То есть...

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Проверил в IE, там нету. Проверил в Chrome вот там вылазит. Проверил расширения, там ничего подозрительного и похожего нету. Стоит AdBlock. 
Видимо дело в самом Chrome. Хотя следует уточнить, что если вызывать просмотр кода элемента, то там эта строка присутствует, если же просто просмотреть исходный код всей страницы, то он в порядке - такой как и должен быть.
Как избавиться или что это такое?

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, дело в Хроме. **Что бы избавится смените браузер!** Не хочется говорить, что гугл обнаглел в край, но стремятся они контролировать все. Поговаривают, что хром отправляет подробную инфу на сервера гугла, о посещенных сайтах и о самом поведении пользователя.